# Cannot read property 'cnt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

This is my code snippet

```
pastActions = res['data']['list']['names']['blk'].cnt
```

But I get to see below error

```
its throws error as Cannot read property 'cnt' of undefined
```

This is because the parent of `cnt` is undefined, it might even fail when any of these properties `data` or `list` or `names` or `blk` is undefined.

I have replaced it as below

```
res['data'] && res['data']['list] && res['data']['list']['names'] && res['data']['list']['names']['blk'] && res['data']['list']['names']['blk'].cnt ? res['data']['list']['names']['blk'].cnt : '';
```

and it works, but is there any optimized way to check the same?

Comment: well, you could use `.` notation instead, that saves 3 characters per level

Comment: Hi @HH837, you can use lodash _.get function. You have an option to return a default value when you have any of the property in the object as undefined.
check here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get
`Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.`

Comment: `try { pastActions = res.data.list.names.blk.cnt; } catch(e) { }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash `_.get` function. You have an option to return a default value when you have any of the property in the object as undefined. 
check here: [lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get](http://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get)